# What is the plural form of "Software"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it correct to use *softwares*, as in the following sentence?

> There are various video conversion softwares in the market.

Comment: @roman, What's wrong with the word *maths*? It's the standard abbreviation of *mathematics* everywhere except the USA. There's nothing specifically Indian about it.

Comment: @TRIG: there you have it "except the USA". I'm used to hearing "math" vs "maths", that's why "maths" sounds wrong to me [no offense to Indian people :D]

Comment: I believe this issue arises because people started using software as a short form for software program.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For all I know, *software* is uncountable, so it's perfectly fine to say "there is various software". If you don't like how that sounds (I know many people who don't), you can always go with "there are various software packages", "there are various pieces of software" or something like that. An even simpler alternative would be "programs". Depending on the context of your sample sentence, even "video converters" might work, if it's already clear that you are talking about software.

**Edit:** I have checked [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/software), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/software) and [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/software), none of them mention *softwares* at all.

Comment: Agreed, it is uncountable and "softwares" sounds very wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Common error I have to correct in non-native writing (particularly from speakers of languages where "software" or a contraction "soft" is used as a countable loan word, including French, Dutch and German).

Comment: my softwarez is borkened.

Comment: It's a mass noun. No plural.

Comment: As a native speaker and in the field of programming software, I honestly cannot remember ever having used 'software' with an 's.' In fact, I am sure I have never used it.  Many times I have said something like 'We will need to / create / use / buy this software.' If I wanted to use it in the plural, it immediately becomes an adjective to describe something else 'software solutions, software programs, software <some noun with an s>

Comment: "There are various pieces of software", is what I'd use.

Comment: I might blend your first and last suggestion to make "that are various software video converters" or perhaps "there are various software programs that convert videos".

Comment: '[S]oftware is uncountable, so it's perfectly fine to say "there is various software".' _There is various cattle_?

Comment: I don't know why, but everytime I hear someone say "softwares", it sounds like fingernails scratching a chalk board.  It really irritates me to no end.  I think some of it has to do with an a pretentious tone that usually goes along with it.

Comment: I'm having to cite this as a duplicate. _Please_ make explicit that 'There is various software' is a different usage from OP's; you're using the adjectival where he uses the peripheral determiner, and you don't bother to clarify. Even with the adjectival usage, 'there is various software' is about as normal-sounding as 'there is various rice'.

Comment: Just returned here, and was about to say that 'there is various rice' etc sounds terrible, when I realised I'd already done so.

Answer (score 42):

Just a note to clear up any confusion: I believe the answer provided by [RegDwight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/plural-form-of-software/4147#4147) is correct; **but** I also want to point out that *because* the word "software" is uncountable, there is no such thing as a "plural form."

What I mean is this: don't misinterpret the accepted answer to imply that the following sentence is correct:

> The company Microsoft produces many software.

The above is problematic for the same reason that the following sentence is problematic:

> My bottle is full of many water.

So again: to answer your question directly, there *is* no plural form. Software is like water; you can have "a lot" of it, but you can't have "many" (or "dozens", or "hundreds", etc.) of it. You can, however, as the other answers have already indicated, have "many *pieces* of it" (just like you can have "many *bottles* of water").

Comment: Prefer "much" to "a lot of" in this context.

Comment: I agree with this answer, that "software" is uncountable. But oddly, Wolfram has an ad campaign for Mathematica going right now with the slogan "One software to rule them all." I think that's a mistake, but it's unusual for a reputable geek company like that to let a grammar error slip out. Maybe the countable usage of "software" is creeping into accepted English.

Comment: Intersting.  Consider people.  It is countable in some cases and uncountable in others.  We can say the "People of Europe" to mean all individual "persons" in Europe.  We can also say the "Peoples of Europe" to mean the various population groups of Europe.

Answer (score 13):

I avoid that by saying *"software products"*.

Comment: Other options: *software solutions*, *applications*, *programs*.

Comment: Or "They sell many types of software".

Answer (score 7):

I would use *programs* instead:

> There are various video conversion programs in the market.

*Software*, in my opinion, is better used as the general *concept* (as opposed to *hardware*, say). All of the *programs* on my PC are *software*. My *hardware* consists of a CPU, memory, fans, screen, etc.

---

Oh, and also I can't resist to refer to the recently common half-joke *codes* (as in "plz show me the codes" so frequent in certain programming forums).

Comment: Get your memes straight.  It's ["Gimme-teh-codez!"](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=site:stackoverflow.com+gimme+teh+codez)

Comment: Software and program can mean the same things but often do not. A program is typically a single entity, whereas, software is typically many programs working together in a system.