# Is "a software" really never correct?

Tags: software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't we use the indefinite article with 'software'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/why-dont-we-use-the-indefinite-article-with-software)

In France I have always been told that saying "a software" is not correct English (as a nominal compound), and that "a piece of software" or "a software program/package/product/system" must be used instead.

Recently I have doubts... is there any case where it is actually correct?

Examples found on the Internet:

- SalsaJ, a software for data analysis at school
- So if you sold a software which required your customer to pay a monthly fee, [...]

Comment: Use "software application" or "software system" (or simply "application" or "system") if you want a singular form.

Comment: It is very important, in English, to understand the distinction between *things* and *stuff*. Software is *stuff*. If you don't understand this, your write programs that say things like, "You see a sand here."

Comment: If your native language is not English, then it may not be good trying to figure this out from the Internet, using things written by OTHERS whose native language is not English ...

Comment: Those examples simply prove that the Internet has mistakes on it, which we surely all already know.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, this is always wrong. Both examples you provide contain incorrect usage of the term "software." (A mistake is still a mistake even if many people make it.)

However, there might be special cases where you'd see the article preceding software.

For example:

> A software solution would be better for the problem than a hardware one.

The indefinite article "a" modifies "solution", not "software", in this case in spite of preceding "software" in this case.

Comment: Although it's wrong in the examples provided, it's not true to say that you can _never_ use the article "a" followed by the word "software". The sentence "I think a software solution would be better than a hardware one" is perfectly valid, for example.

Comment: In other words, only when the article "a" is *not* modifying software. (In your example, "a" and "software" are both modifying "solution".) In other words, never.

Comment: @sq33G: I think that should be specified in the answer.

Comment: @AndyF the original question calls "a software" `a nominal compound`. While the article "a" is not really forming a compound here with "software", I think the meaning of the question is clearly referring to the case where "a" is modifying "software", not another word that follows it.

Comment: Well then, please forgive my lack of reading comprehension.

Comment: If I understand correctly, software is uncountable and "a software" is as wrong as "a water", "a milk", "a news", "an information", and so on.

Comment: @Vaibhav - thanks for clarifying my answer while I slept!

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, My pleasure.

Comment: “A mistake is still a mistake even if many people make it.” – I’m really not that happy with it. I agree in general but language *does* change. And it doesn’t change when we decide it does but when enough people change usage. I’m not sure that it’s happening in this particular case but it’s interesting that [the frequency of usage of “a software” is almost on par with “a piece of software”](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+software+is%2CA+piece+of+software+is&year_start=1970&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: A simple search for "a software" does not permit one to determine whether the word "software" is being used as an adjective ("a software programmer," "a software solution") or as an unadorned noun, so I am not convinced your findings are relevant. True, language does change - grammar gets simpler, words are adopted or pick up new meanings, but for now... this is a mistake, plain and simple.

Answer (score 28):

Think of it this way: would you say "a tableware" or "a glassware"? The word "ware" means "commodity". Everything that applies to "tableware" and "glassware" also applies to "software".

The correct usage is "a piece of software" or something in that vein. I prefer "a program" or "a computer program" myself. Other alternatives are: an application, a computer application, an app, a software tool.

(FWIW: as a software developer myself, I assure you that devs never use the term "a software" when they communicate.)

Comment: Yes, the same with "hardware". However, I've heard software developers (for whom English is a second language) incorrectly use "a software" and "softwares".

Answer (score 1):

It can be used correctly but not in the manner in which you have demonstrated.

Use in adjective form as in "A software package" is acceptable.

Comment: Again (see AndyF's comment above to James McLoed's answer), here "a" is modifying "package", not "software".

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the use of 'a software' (in speech at least), as suggested in the question, has become rampant in recent times.

> "What is MS Word?"
>   "I know. It's a software."
>
> "This process takes too much time."
>   "There should be a software for this."

But that does NOT make it grammatically/technically correct.

Comment: I have never heard this. At least not from a native English speaker.

Comment: @Groky Your experience isn’t really that relevant. What’s relevant is that it *is* widely used, [as easily demonstrated by looking on Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+software+is%2CA+piece+of+software+is&year_start=1970&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Groky As most of the English-speakers are not native, *"a software"* is more and more used. Therefore I think *"a software"* could become accepted as correct in some decades. Google Ngram says [*"A software is"* became in 2008 more common than *"A software program is"*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+software+is%2CA+piece+of+software+is%2CA+software+program+is%2CA+software+application+is%2CA+computer+application+is&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=). But it is not yet the case using lowercase *"a software is"*. Let's see...

Comment: @Groky Agreed. What you might hear is *a piece of software*.