# Can you use an article in front of the word "software"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t we use the indefinite article with ‘software’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/why-dont-we-use-the-indefinite-article-with-software)

Can you say "a software" or "the software"? E.g.

> That is how you use the software.

Comment: In exceptional contexts, *a software* does appear acceptable. However, it certainly not used in general to mean an item of software or a software product. The indefinite article is used only when *software* is adjectival modifying a noun.

Comment: @Hugo We cannot make a blanket statement. See also my comments. The answer at linked post, too, makes the same mistake, I must say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software is [uncountable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_noun) which means that it does not accept the indefinite article "a". In some cases, you can say "some" to convey this more indefinite meaning. It is perfectly acceptable to use a definite article on an uncountable noun and say "the software".

Note: In more rare cases "a software" can be used to denote "a *piece* of software". Piece, being countable, allows this to happen. Another example is that while the word beer is typically uncountable, "a beer", often comes to mean "a *glass* of beer".

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph.   However, while "a beer" is perfectly acceptable, saying "a software" is going to get you funny looks at best, and be called flat-out incorrect at worst.

Comment: @Lynn Yes, I completely agree. While the usage is very rare, I wanted to make the point that when an uncountable noun acts countable, it is typically done by leaving out a word that would have made the noun phrase countable. Beer was the best way I could think to lead into this as it is considered both countable and uncountable based on usage for this very reason. See the usage note here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beers

Comment: A more common example could be "There's a software for that too" -- with a meaning similar to "a certain software product."

Comment: @Kris I don't know if that's a British/American/other thing, but that's categorically wrong in British English. It would be *There is software for that* or, more likely, *You can get software for that* or even *There's an app for that.* But **never** "a software" as a countable noun. Even though you can say "Some breads have currants in," you can't say "some softwares are badly-written".

Comment: @specialscope Yes, you can always refer to a particular instance of a mass noun: the water, the bread, the people... In your sentence you are referring to particular software.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You still don't seem to see this as a noun being used in an adjectival sense. It's no AmE/BrE/regionalism -- but grammatically correct when the elided noun is visualized correctly. It is clear from your incorrect example of "*softwares*" -- no, it's not a noun but an adjective here.

Comment: @Kris You're wrong, at least for British English. *Software* used an adjective never has an elided noun; it's either explicitly an adjective (with a stated noun), or it's a noun. If it's a noun, it's a mass noun and "softwares" is not correct. I'm quite happy to see and use "a software solution", for example, but "a software for that" makes software into a noun, and in that case "a software" is not correct.

Comment: ...However I would say that in my earlier comment to specialscope I could have written "you are referring to a particular software" and that would have been correct in much the same way as referring to a particular cheese (Cheddar or Yarg), or a particular water (Buxton or sea-water) or similar.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I agree with what you said about software never having an elided noun.  I would go a step further to say that "a particular software" may be correct in some sense, but sounds equally wrong to my ears.  "A particular software *system*" would be the more common usage.