# Do we use article for social media or not, and why?

Tags: social-media

When we consider social media as a singular word, why we don't use article for it? As far as I know in new dictionaries we consider it as 'singular'.

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you mean the expression "social media", or the names of services such as Twitter and Facebook?

Comment: Compare: [Why don't we use the indefinite article with 'software'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/why-dont-we-use-the-indefinite-article-with-software)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media) is happy still to use 'Social media **are** interactive technologies and digital channels that ...' [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/social-media.asp#:~:text=Social%20media%20is%20a%20computer,of%20virtual%20networks%20and%20communities.&text=The%20largest%20social%20media%20networks,Twitter%2C%20YouTube%2C%20and%20TikTok.) has: 'Social media is a computer-based technology that facilitates the sharing of ideas, thoughts'. But there are precedents for singular agreement of the noncount usage: 'Radio (etc) is still a ...'

Comment: We don't use an article because it's a term for a category, not a specific item.