# few/little/some software (in plural)

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english, uncountable-nouns, irregular-plurals

I would like to say:

Available calculation methods are limited to few software. With "few", I mean 3 programs. However, "software" is an uncountable noun. "Some" and "little" sound also weird?

> Available calculation methods are limited to few software.

> Available calculation methods are limited to little software.

> Available calculation methods are limited to some software.

Comment: Linited to few software _applications_

Comment: 'Software' is probably in the process of being countified, though I'd agree 'softwares' is non-standard at the present time.

Comment: Do answers here answer your question? [What is the plural form of "Software"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/what-is-the-plural-form-of-software) Various workarounds are suggested.

Comment: 'Software' is a general term: a category. It is not synonymous with 'program' or 'application'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, "software" is uncountable. This leaves you with a number of options, such as "software packages" or "pieces of software".